# Where does cmake look for .cmake scripts?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to `execute_process` in `cmake` like this

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P myScript.cmake
```

This only works if the file, `myScript.cmake` is in the same working directory.

Three related questions:

1. Does `cmake` have a standard location to look for `.cmake` scripts?
2. Is there a `cmake` variable I can define to tell `cmake` where to look? or
3. Should I always give a full path to the script (i.e., `-P ${PATH_VAR}/myScript.cmake`)?

Comment: CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.   http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html, though you would still need to call include(myScript).

Comment: @StAlphonzo `include(myScript)` is *similar* to calling `execute_process` as shown, but not identical.  Using `include` is almost like pasting the contents of `myScript.cmake` into the calling CMakeLists.txt - you have access to all the environment and variables at that point.  Calling `execute_process` starts a brand new CMake process which has none of the calling script's variables set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does `cmake` have a standard location to look for `.cmake` scripts?

For [`execute_process`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/execute_process.html), no.  The `find_XXX` commands (e.g. [`find_file`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/find_file.html)) and [`include`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/include.html) do though.

> Is there a `cmake` variable I can define to tell `cmake` where to look?

Again, for `execute_process`, no.  For `find_xxx` or `include`, you can set the variable [`CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html).

> Should I always give a full path to the script (i.e., `-P ${PATH_VAR}/myScript.cmake`)?

That's a good option; passing a full path leaves no room for uncertainty.  However, you can get away with a relative path too.  The default working directory for `execute_process` is the [`CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.html), so you can pass the path to the script relative to that.

Alternatively you can specify the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` in the `execute_process` call either as a full path or relative to the `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`.

If you feel your script is in a standard location, you could consider "finding" it first using a call to `find_file`.  This would yield the full path to the script if found and that variable can be used in your `execute_process` call.

Comment: CMake does have standard locations to look for `.cmake` scripts:
http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries#How_package_finding_works

Comment: @VictorL - Well, the question was asking specifically about `execute_process` in which case my original answers were correct.  However, I can see that the title leaves a bit of room for ambiguity, so I've updated my answer to cover `include` and `find_xxx` commands too.